# Frame in Selenium cannot be found

Tags: selenium

I am new to Selenium and trying to practise with icloud.com. I wrote the code below but the frame cannot be located, but when I do on console the frame is being located.

```
driver.get("https://www.icloud.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='Apple Id Sign-In'][@id='auth-frame'][@class='atv4 sc-view']")));
```

Comment: are you facing any error ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually your site take time to load `iframe` Need to use `ExplicitWait` to visibility of `iframe`

```
    driver.get("https://www.icloud.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);     

    WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='Apple Id Sign-In'][@id='auth-frame'][@class='atv4 sc-view']")));

    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='Apple Id Sign-In'][@id='auth-frame'][@class='atv4 sc-view']")));

    driver.findElement(By.id("appleId")).sendKeys("hello");
```

Comment: Thanks much! It worked when I added wait for iframe, really appreciate